# How to find the number of iteration in this while loop - operation count

Tags: c++, complexity-theory

I'm confused about how to do the operation count for a while loop specifically the number of iterations.
I do understand how to find the number of iteration for a regular loop (from 0 to n) and also for binary search (log2n) but this piece of code utilizes the case of true and false. the number of iteration would depend on if "more" is true and "found" is false.

What would be the worst case scenario for this? the item is not found?
In the code below, the commented parts are the operation count for that line.

List is a linked list structure of N nodes:

```
void FindItem(Node *list, Item item, Node *&loc, bool &found){
    bool more = true;                 // 1
    loc = list; found = false;        // 2
    while (more && !found) {          // (number of iterations)
        if (item < loc->info)         // 2 * (number of iteration)
            more = false;             // (0 or 1)*number of iterations
        else if (item == loc->info)   // 2 * (number of iteration)
            found=true;               // (0 or 1)*number of iterations
        else {
            loc = loc->next;          // (0 or 2) * (number of iteration)
            more = (loc != NULL);     // (0 or 2)*number of iterations
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to count the number of iterations or do you want to know the asymptotic complexity?

Comment: Honestly, the *worst* case scenario is passing a null `list` to this function, in which case the entire thing degenerates into a festival of undefined behavior. Regardless, this is little more than a linked list enumeration, and as such the asymptotic complexity is O(n). The number of actual statements executed (which you shouldn't care about as much as the complexity) is entirely dependent on evaluation of members, and we're not privy to that.

Comment: Specifically, find the number of iteration for this while loop

Comment: if it is about counting then simply add a counter, increment it at the top of the loop and print it at the end of the function

Comment: Yikes I thought `item<loc->` was a typo in a template declaration at first. Please add some whitespace!

Comment: @ShippyDippy That specific question isn't answerable with only what you've shown. Assuming a valid list was passed in, it could jettison on the very first iteration. Or... somewhere in the middle, or reach the end. Your question states "what would be the *worst* case scenario". Your comment above states, "find the number of iterations". Those can be the same value in *one* case: enumerating the full list; otherwise they will differ.

Comment: This question is something I would have to figure out on paper. I'm guessing the number of iterations would depend on the size of the list?

Comment: Oops, I confused "operation count" with "iteration count". I deleted my answer since it dealt with iteration count.

Comment: please consider that number of iterations, absolute count of operations and asymptotic complexity are different things. One can write algorithms that wildy differ in those three metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a school exercise or a homework question.
The fact that you need to answer on paper, pretty much confirms that.

So what you are looking for is probably "[Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)" complexity.
And in that case, you are looking at a simple 0 .. n loop, which you claim to know, since at most, the loop can run over the entire list.

The name of the condition variable `more` and the condition it self are a clear clue that the code is nothing more than a linier search on a sorted list.